# How well does v8 optimise nested functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, optimization, v8

Sometimes I see code like:

```
var doSomething = function(object){
    var results = []
    var doSomethingElse = function(object){
        ...
    }
    results.push(doSomethingElse(...))
    return results
}
```

Organised this way because `doSomethingElse` only has meaning within `doSomething`. Performance is acceptable, so this is merely a curiosity: how well does v8 optimise for nested functions? **Is a new copy of doSomethingElse() being instantiated each time doSomething() is called?**

Answer (score 1):

I do not know about how well optimized it is, I do not think you will ever get information like that, that kind of question is way too broad, I know because I have asked those questions before, and the answer is always "try it, profile and see".

Then again, I would not be answering to say just that.

There are 2 sources I have found that recommend AGAINST using those, because they add another step for the engine, as it needs to create the function each time, and add a level to a scope chain.

The exact reasons and tests here:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/stop-nesting-functions-but-not-all-of-them--net-22315

[https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/optimizing-javascript](https://web.archive.org/web/20140625171529/https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/optimizing-javascript)

This should probably be in a comment, but I can't comment yet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about V8 internals, but closures should be pretty well optimized I would assume. But to answer the other part of your question: yes, a new `doSomethingElse` is created per `doSomething` call. This is speaking from a language point of view. Technically a smart JIT could be optimizing this already.

If you're worried about this, you can guarantee the `doSomethingElse` is created once by defining it in a self-invoking function:

```
var doSomething = (function() {
  var doSomethingElse = function(object){ // only defined once
      ...
  };

  return function(object){ // the actual doSomething function
      var results = [];
      results.push(doSomethingElse(...));
      return results;
  };
}());
```

You just need to remember that this will persist `doSomethingElse` across all `doSomething` calls. So if you do anything stateful you might see some unexpected behavior.

Comment: This isn't a closure: no variables from `doSomething()` are being closed over, it's a straight return of a value. The garbage collector could remove everything from `doSomething()`'s scope after the function returns.

Comment: @mikemaccana That's true, your original example _can_ be a closure, but since your nested function is just receiving an `object` to work on exclusively instead of using enclosed variables, it's valid to use this non-closure optimization instead.